# Empty white screen while trying to compile and run ionic2

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I am trying to create a simple HTTP post service for my login page.

For some weird reasons, i encountered errors in my app.bundle.js:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined

Using ionic2 tutorial sample project, I have done the following:

In my app.js (so my service would be accessible globally)

```
import {HttpService} from './services/httpService';
@App({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  config: {} ,// http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
  providers: [HttpService]
})
```

and set the rootPage to my login page

```
this.rootPage = LoginPage;
```

In my log-in.html

```
 <button  class="button button-block" (click)="loginSuccess()" style="width:70%;">
   <strong>Log In</strong>
 </button>
```

In my log-in.js

```
import {App, Page, Platform, IonicApp, NavParams, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {HttpService} from '../../services/httpService';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/log-in/log-in.html'
})

export class LoginPage {

  constructor(nav,app,httpService) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.app = app;
    this.httpService = httpService;
  }

  loginSuccess() {
    console.log("Invoked Method!");

       this.httpService.loginService(event.target.value).subscribe(
         data => {this.httpService = data.results; console.log(data);},
         err => this.logError(err),
         () => console.log('Invoked Login Service Complete')
       );
  }
}
```

httpService.JS

```
import { Inject } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http } from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export class httpService {
    static get parameters() {
        return [[Http]];
    }

    constructor(http) {
        this.http = http
    }

    loginService(httpService) {
      console.log("Service Function Variable: "+httpService);

    //  var body = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password+" &ipAddress="+ip;
      var body = "username=" + "admin" + "&password=" + "admin" +" &ipAddress="+"127.0.0.1";
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

      var url = 'http://localhost/WS/Login.asmx/Login';
      return this.http.post(url,body, {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());

    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm just trying to get my services up. All I am presented is a **blank white screen** and errors from app.bundle.js (which is generated at compile time), yet I do not have any compile errors while compiling.

[image]

And the app.bundle.js code which have errors are:

```
exports.isJsObject = isJsObject;
function print(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}
```

and

```
var inits = injector.getOptional(application_tokens_1.APP_INITIALIZER);
```

which I have no idea as this is generated automatically. I apologise for the code dump(I have tried to remove unnecessary stuff) as I do not know which part of it went wrong.

My ionic version is : 2.0.0-beta.25 if that helps.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: @A_Singh in ionic 2, that means app level? I'm not really that sure.

Comment: that is a custom Decorator implemented by ionic. anyway it's ok , probably something else is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the decorator @Injectable on your service...

export class httpService {

should be (i think, I´m using v24, maybe in v25 is different?)

import {Injectable, Inject} from "angular2/core";

@Injectable
export class httpService {

Comment: Also, this is a good place to learn about what you are triyng to do: http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-handling-a-simple-user-authorization/2/

Comment: To add on, Removing the providers in app.js and adding it inside log-in.js instead works.

Answer (score 2):

Had a look at your code. I could see that you have used Headers but haven't imported them in your code. In the httpService.js file modify the import statement as shown below.

```
import { Http, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
```

app.bundle.js is simply a bundle of modules generated by webpack which is popular module loader used by Ionic.

P.S: If you are trying to implement an authentication system in your Ionic 2 application, I recommend you to have a look [here](http://tphangout.com/rest-api-authentication-for-your-ionic-2-app-part-1/).

Hope this helped you. Thanks.